# Is g++ on cygwin any different from what I get on Linux platform?

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin

Can I start installing boost libraries, ACE framework and use it as my home Linux server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The G++ on Cygwin is very similar to that on any other platform.  You should be able to use it with Boost if you can't find the Boost libraries you want pre-compiled for Cygwin.

However, Cygwin is not Linux; you won't be able to use it as your 'home Linux server'.  Cygwin gives a Linux-like interface to Windows, but it is still running on Windows, not Linux.

Comment: The Boost libraries are available through Cygwin's installer.